# Android: Error claiming table doesn't exist in database but it does

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having trouble querying my SQLite database using Android. I keep getting either an error saying the table "users" doesn't exist in DB or the column name "fname" doesn't exist but both of them do.

The only table that the database recognises is android_metadata. Here is my code for the DataBaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.Main/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "CSLearnDB";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.


        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            this.close();
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

    this.close();

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public Cursor dbSelect(String table, String[] select){

    return myDataBase.query(table, select, null, null, null, null, null);

}
```

}

Here is the code in my Main onCreate method:

```
public class Hello_AppActivity extends Activity {


String tag = "Events";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);


    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }



    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    results.add("TEST");

    String[] x = {"sname"};

    Cursor c = myDbHelper.dbSelect("users", x);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);



    if (c != null ) {

        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String firstName = c.getString(0);

                results.add(firstName);

                results.add("TEST 2");

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        } 
    }else{

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, results);

    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure the database was copied correctly.  If the table is actually in there, my bet is the empty database is created earlier than you think and its not copying the one you want.

You should be able to adb shell in and run sqlite3 on the command line to query the db too.

Comment: I ended up created a new test database and it worked successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you so sure they exist? Have you checked the database file in a SQLite browser?

It looks like you never actually create the table. You will need a line like

```
sqlDB.execSQL("create table users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, fname text);");
```

which I put in the `onCreate()` method of my helper, but you might be able to place it somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have checked it in SQLite Browser and it is there. The reason I haven't created the table is because it already exists in the database which I created using SQLite Broswer.